# trying to perform a search from a winform application wrong encoding

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, search-engine

[image]this is a test to perform a search query from winforms appliaction

in my language it is "trying to search in my language"

the output shows in the browsers - bing search box using firefox client

is 
    ���� ���� ���� ���

thinking of the utf-8 encoding i have desperatly made this test 
this is before understanding the procedure /structure ...so i guess it is little awkward syntax for the encoding part, though inside the VS  it does return  hebrew(:

```
        private void But_FullPageExtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tbxVal = TBX_SearchMain.Text;
            var searchPhrase = UrlSources.CustomUrlTbxVal;


            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tbxVal);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) bytes[i] ^= 0x5a;
            var ut8STR = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var savedAsBs64STR = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            var readbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(savedAsBs64STR);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) bytes[i] ^= 0x5a;
            string final= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var stringa = final;
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < 1)
                    Run_TheClickFullPage(searchPhrase.Replace("_RobSearchT_", stringa).Replace("_RobPageArg_", (i + 1).ToString()), i);
                else if (i == 1)
                    Run_TheClickFullPage(UrlSources.SecondResPage, i);
                else Run_TheClickFullPage(UrlSources.restResPage.Replace("RobArg1_", (i).ToString()).Replace("_RobArg2", (i - 1).ToString()), i);

            }

        }
```

**what encoding do i need to implement ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use UriEncoding, like this:

```
string hebrew = "שלום, עולם";
string query = "http://bing.com?q={0}";
Uri url = new Uri(String.Format(query, Uri.EscapeDataString(hebrew)));
```